# BottlePy - How can I find the current route from within a hook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I have the following hook in [BottlePy](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/):

```
@bottle_app.hook('before_request')
def update_session():
    # do stuff
    return
```

And some routes:

```
@bottle_app.route('/')
def index():
    return render('index')

@bottle_app.route('/example')
def example():
    return render('example')
```

**From within `update_session()`, how can I determine which route is being called?**

I have looked through the documentation to no avail, but surely this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The request has both a `bottle.route` and a `route.handle` entry, both contain the same value:

```
from bottle import request

print request['bottle.route']
```

This isn't documented; I had to find it [in the `bottle.py` source](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L754). The value is a `Route` instance; it has both a `.name` and a `.rule` attribute you could inspect to determine which route was matched.

```
if request['bottle.route'].rule == '/':
    # matched the `/` route.
```

For your specific example this is perhaps overkill, since you are only matching simple paths, but for more complex rules with regular expression rules this would work better than trying to match the `request.path` attribute (but it'd be a good idea to give your routes a `name` value).

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. I wonder why it isn't documented? Thanks!

Comment: You can consider this API stable. It's not documented because I planned to implement ``request.route`` as a shorthand but forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bottle import request

@bottle_app.hook('before_request')
def update_session():
    print request.path
    return
```

Should do what your asking for

You can then store routes in a dictionary.

```
my_routes = {"/":lambda: 5}
event = my_routes.get(request.path, lambda: None)
print event()
```